# I'm having issues getting the qwt widget to work correctly with Qt-Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, qwt

I'm having issues getting qwt 6.1.0 to work correctly with Qt-Creator 5.1.0.  It works correctly when I launch the stand alone version of Qt-Designer and everything compiles and runs correctly when I use Qt-Creator.  However the designer that is built into Qt-Creator does not display the qwt widgets correctly on any forms nor give me the option to add new qwt widgets.

I'm using Qt Creator 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS2012 with OpenGL).  I've also downloaded and compiled Qwt 6.1.0 with the aforementioned Qt-Creator, by simply opening the qwt.pro file and compiling it.  Once it was compiled I used the 'nmake' and 'nmake install' commands from the visual studio command prompt as directed in the Qwt instructions (http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html).  I then copied the qwt_designer_plugin.dll to the C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\designer\ and C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\msvc2012_64_opengl\plugins\designer\ directories.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I can manually launch Qt-Designer and just compile with Qt-Creator, but it is kind of annoying to have to constantly switch back and forth and not be able to use the designer that is bundled into Qt-Creator.

EDIT #1: 
I've also set the path environment variable to C:\Qwt-6.1.0\lib\ as instructed in the qwt installation documenation.  Additionally I've set the following in the Qt project file (.pro) that I'm testing with:

```
CONFIG  += qwt
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qwt-6.1.0\include\
LIBS += C:\Qwt-6.1.0\lib\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be on the compatibility of your QTCreator with the the ACTUAL QT framework you built QWT against.

The *Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 522 MB)* package provided in QT-Project.org/Download has the *QT libraries* built against **MSVCR110 (C++ 2012) 64 bits** where as the actual *QTCreator.exe* is built against **MSCVR100 (C++ 2010)**. That's why the QWT plugin load successfully form the stand-alone QT Designer that comes in the QT framework, but not on the QT creator that comes in the Tools/ directory. To check this, load the QTCreator executable in Dependency Walker and you'll see.

My recommendation is that you **download the source code of QT, build it with your compiler and then compile the QWT using the same compiler**. A bit tedious but at least you'll be sure that your plugins will load.

Comment: This is what eventually worked out for me.  After rebuilding everything with the same compiler I was able to get everything working together nicely.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you have to adjust your PATH variable:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;${QWT_ROOT}\lib
```

Just copying the dll is not enough, if your did not compile your qwt 'selfcontained':

> When the plugin has not been built including the Qwt library ( see
>   QwtDesignerSelfContained in qwtconfig.pri ) the Qt Designer/Creator
>   also needs to locate the Qwt libraries.

And btw... There is no Qt-Creator 5.0.1. What you mean is Qt 5.0.1. The Qt-Creator is only a tool within your Qt package.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  Unfortunately I've already set the path environment variable to C:\Qwt-6.1.0\lib\.  I also realize that C:\Qwt-6.1.0\ doesn't exactly follow where I have the rest of the Qt stuff installed c:\QT\, but it was the default directly used in the .pri files.

Comment: You did not write that before. ;-) If it is not that, it might be, as stated in the docs, that your Qt-Creator is incompatible. Even though you compiled your qwt yourself, it does not mean that the Qt-Creator binary was compiled with the same or compatible compiler. You could compile your Qt-Creator yourself. It is not that hard. But before: QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS. I agree with the docs: Debugging why plugins are not loading is hellish.

Comment: I think I'll try compiling it all this weekend as per your suggestion and I'll let you know how it turns out.  I just find it odd that it works with the stand along designer, but not with the one built into creator.  Thanks again!

Comment: Here is someone with exactly the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946192/qwt-designer-plugin-is-inaccesable-via-qtcreator-built-in-designer. No guarantee, but the fact that the standalone designer sees the plugins, but the designer within qt-creator not, is a strong hint, that it could be a version mismatch.